# Solr JSON Update via Restcall

Tags: solr

Not able to Add or update solr document via restart this particular format, But same happening via solr admin console.

Content:
{'id':'1', 'Name':'jaga', '*childDocuments*':[{'id':'1_1', 'Class':'A'},{'id':'1_2', 'Class':'B'}]}

Child and Parent relation documents

Comment: So what happens? Do you get an error message? How are you submitting the documents? Are you using Solr's format for adding documents, or just submitting raw JSON?

Comment: 1) It updates as a single document when add via post (restcall) eg: "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[{"id":"1_1","Class":["A"],"_version_":1603320276661043200,"Class_str":["A"]},{"id":"1_2","Class":["B"],"_version_":1603320276664188928,"Class_str":["B"]},{"id":"1","Name":["Ajay"],"_version_":1603320276664188929,"Name_str":["Ajay"]}]}}

2) No i didn't get any error message
3)Updating via rest , if i do in admin console its working fine
4)Raw JSON

Comment: But where are you posting? How? What is the result? There are multiple endpoints that behaves differently based on configuration and possibly Content-Type headers. Expand your question with relevant information so your problem can be _reproduced_.

Comment: i'm using header as {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 

My data : {'id':'1', 'Name':'jaga', 'childDocuments':[{'id':'1_1', 'Class':'A'},{'id':'1_2', 'Class':'B'}]}

i need to achieve childDocuments

Comment: Please add the details properly formatted to your question. The first response looks like a query response and not a response to an update.

Comment: Yes its adding without child ref value, If i add via restcall without child reference it has one documnets. If i add via admin console it has 3 document with child reference working as expected. Please try with post and admin console update for this json :{'id':'1', 'Name':'jaga', 'childDocuments':[{'id':'1_1', 'Class':'A'},{'id':'1_2', 'Class':'B'}]}